# "Does not accept Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository" Error in shopware 5 PhpStan analysis

Tags: doctrine, return-type, shopware, phpstan

I have used the following lines of code in my shopware 5 plugin

```
use HatslogicAbandonedCartNotification\Models\AbandonedCartItems as AbandonedCartItemsModel;
use HatslogicAbandonedCartNotification\Models\Repository as AbandonedCartItemsRepository;
```

I have a variable

```
/ **
  * @var AbandonedCartItemsRepository
  * /
private $abandonedCartItemsRepository;
```

In the function __construct I set the variable

```
$this->abandonedCartItemsRepository = $this->modelManager->getRepository (AbandonedCartItemsModel :: class);
```

But in PHPstan analysis I got the following error

> Property HatslogicAbandonedCartNotification \ Subscriber \
>   CartNotification :: $ abandonedCartItemsRepository
>              (HatslogicAbandonedCartNotification \ Models \ Repository) does not accept Doctrine \ ORM \ EntityRepository.

Anything wrong with my code? or is it an ignorable error?

Comment: What's in the `$this->modelManager` property?

Comment: Object of Shopware\Components\Model\ModelManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Shyim

I have fixed the issue by

```
/** @var AbandonedCartItemsRepository $abandonedCartItemsRepository */
$abandonedCartItemsRepository = $this->modelManager->getRepository (AbandonedCartItemsModel :: class);
$this->abandonedCartItemsRepository = $abandonedCartItemsRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it to a variable and make a phpdoc. That should fix it :)
Otherwise try the doctrine phpstan extension